# Exceptions Thrown By std::vector::erase()

Tags: c++, exception, vector

Going through the documentation of the std::vector::erase() method, it states that the method will not throw any exceptions unless the index passed on to it is an invalid index. I have the following snippet in my C++ program:

```
vector<int> remove_element(vector<int> v,int xj,int n)
{
    std::vector<int> nl(v);

    if (xj < 0)
    {
        xj = n + xj;
    }
    if(xj>=n)
    {
        xj = xj%n;
    }
    nl.erase(nl.begin() + xj);//This line is causing a segmentation fault

   return nl;
}
```

v is a predefined vector in the program and n is its size, nl is made a copy of that vector using the copy constructor and so as not to reflect the changes made in nl to v. xj is the index to be erased from the vector. I have also included the if statements to ensure that an invalid index is not passed on to erase(). But the problem is that I get a Segmentation Fault when it is run on external data on a server. I can't find where it is going wrong.

---EDITED---
I have replaced the negative index check with @StoryTeller's answer.
But I still get a segmentation fault when I try to run the program on the server on [three test cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChMVx.png).
When I replace :

```
nl.erase(nl.begin() + xj);
```

with,

```
nl[xj] = -1;
```

and later do a check later for -1, then I don't get any Segmentation faults but get [two wrong answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol1lD.png).

I am absolutely sure that the other parts of my code is correct and this is the part which is causing problems.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: if `xj` is less than `-n`, then `xj = n+xj` will remain less than zero.

Comment: I have updated the snippet

Comment: Use vector::size not `n` to remove one potential problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (xj < 0)
{
   xj = n + xj;
}
```

does not guarantee that `xj` will be non-negative after that. I suggest changing it to:

```
while (xj < 0)
{
   xj = n + xj;
}
```

A simpler expression can also be used (Thanks to @StoryTeller):

```
if (xj < 0)
{
   xj = n + (xj % n);
}
```

Comment: If xj < 0 and abs(xj) > n this loop will never terminate.

Comment: @RichardCritten - It will https://ideone.com/SeLmps

Comment: Thanks, @StoryTeller.